# python multiprocessing pool.map() slower than normal execution

Tags: python, multiprocessing

First of all I want to say that I am a beginner in programming with python. So it is possible that my mistake is very obvious. I tried to improve the performance of my code by the usage of the multiprocessing recently. But I wasn't successful yet and hope you can help me.

I have a calculation that needs to be executed for each record of a data set. At all I have 345 records. For each records my calculation needs arround 0.0016 - 0.002 seconds, in sum 0.552 - 0.6 seconds. Technically my CPU has 12 cores. So I expect to speed up this calculation to arround 0.07 to 0.08 seconds by parallelism. Since the calculation is completely independent from other data records, I don't need any kind of synchronisation between the tasks or a shared memory.

I have chosen for the implementation the multiprocessing.pool function. My code works more or less like this:

```
 p = multiprocessing.Pool(core_num)

 for record in range(0, dataset_len):
     task_list.append((const1, const2, dataset[record, :], task_idx))

 output = p.map(calculation_func, task_list)
 p.close()
```

const1, const2 are constants the calculation function calculation_func needs for evaluating the data. task_idx is just a identifier to bring the data in the correct order after calculaton. Only the execution from

```
output = p.map(calculation_func, task_list)
```

needs around 2.2 seconds for execution with core_num = 12 and best I reached was 1.6 seconds with core_num = 4. Both ways slower than just calling the function without using multiprocessing.

What I already tried:

- used starmap instead of map, to replace the tuple of my input list
- I sliced my dataset into threads_num subsets and appended this subsets to task_list to have the same amount of tasks and core_num.

In both cases I added a time.time() at the beginning and the end of calculation_func() and printed the required time for one or 1/12 of all evaluations. The times measured are as small as expected in the beginning.

Questions:

- Have I made a good choice with multiprocessing.pool.map()?
- If i can measure that calculation_func() only needs the expected time - what happens the rest of output = p.map(calculation_func, task_list)
- I excluded the possibility that the different processes try to access the same RAM because of const1 and const2 what cases blockings. According to my understanding of the documentation the initialisation of a process copies all data to new storage cells. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi I still couldn't make progress in this issue. If you could give me an advice which information are helpful for debugging I also really appreciate this.